# Data processing using multithreading java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two folders which contain several csv files. Folder 1 has several csv files and Folder 2 has several csv files. Based on certain conditions, I am comparing csv files (code for which is present in compareCSV(File f1, File f2)) and writing into a new output file.

```
public void traverseThroughFiles(){
      //some filename checking code
      //if output is true call below function
      compareCSV(File f1, File f2)
}
```

Now I wish to use multithreading in java so that I can process multiple files simultaneously. As per my understanding, if we could call function comapareCSV(File f1, File f2) using multiple threads then I should achieve my goal. Number of threads need to be determined by the user. But, consider `numberofThreads = 5`

Are there any functions/classes which are present in java that can solve my problem?

I have tried to use `ThreadPool` and I was unable to implement in my case. Also, how can I use `ExecutorService` in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have more than one hard drive, parallelising the process won't speed up things since your operation is essentially I/O constrained - it would probably even be detrimental to performance.

Assuming that using more than one thread may improve performance, you can simply do:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

executor.submit(() -> compareCSV(f1, f2));
executor.submit(() -> compareCSV(f3, f4));
executor.submit(() -> compareCSV(f5, f6));
executor.submit(() -> compareCSV(f7, f8));
```

and the method will execute in parallel (you will probably want to store the files in some collection and use a loop but you get the idea).

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is working. Except that executor.shutdown() needs to be called after completion.